# Is it possible to have authorization scopes, policies etc in keycloak with SAML?

Tags: authorization, keycloak, saml

I'm following the [official documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_getting_started_hello_world_enabling_authz_services) for keycloak Version 11.0.2 to enable authorization services for a client I have already created. The example focuses on openid-connect. Choosing openid-connect enables hidden items that allow you to enable authorization services. Choosing saml though this is not the case. Can anybody share some thoughts?

Is there a way to enable authorization services using SAML protocol in keycloak?